# How does the keyword "this" work in this example?

Tags: javascript

So in the below code, I was wondering how the `this` keyword works here? Also where does the `i` and `this` go to from the createstoken function?

Does it go to the `this.id` in the token class? If so why?

```
class Player{
    constructor(playerNumber, tokenCount, tokenColor, active = false){
        this.playerNumber = playerNumber
        this.tokenCount = tokenCount
        this.tokenColor = tokenColor
        this.active = active
        this.tokens = [createTokens(21)]
    }
    //creates tokens
    createTokens(num){
        let array = []
        for(let i=0; i<num; i+=1){
            const token = new Token(i, this)
            array.push(token)
        }
        return array = []
    }
}//end player

class Token{
    constructor(){
        this.owner = owner;
        this.id = `token-${index}-${owner.id}`;
        this.dropped = false;
    }

}//end token
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: You sure it works? There are no parameters in the `Token` constructor. Would expect to see `constructor(index, owner)`.

Comment: Why aren't you taking parameters in `Token`? It should be `constructor(index, owner)` or similar.

Comment: check out my answer bro it might help you.

Comment: sorry I realized i missed some code, but the answers did answer my question so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `this` refers to the new object that is being constructed when the instance of the class is created:

```
class Player {
    constructor(playerNumber) {
        this.playerNumber = playerNumber;
        //This refers to whatever object is being created - in the below instance, `this` would refer to `newPlayer`
    }
}

const newPlayer = new Player(25);
```

Comment: Thank you that helps clear it up! I do have some parts missing from the code i realised sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Current object which is invoked will be taken as this.checkout the simple example as i have used "this" variable to construct a object.

"new" keyword can be used in constructor function to refer a unique object.

checkout the example:

```js
function Maker(name,age){
  //current object will be taken as this.
 this.name=name;
  this.age=age;
  return this;
}


let firstObject = new Maker('bathri',22);
let secondObject = new Maker('bathri',22);

let result = [firstObject,secondObject];
console.log("first object",firstObject);
console.log("second object",secondObject);
console.log("result",result);
```